# Erlang set encoding in <?xml> tag with xmerl

Tags: xml, erlang, xmerl

I have a line of code like this:

```
xmerl:export_simple([XmerlRecords], xmerl_xml).
```

It works as expected and generates an IO list of XML. However, the `<?xml>` tag looks like this: `<?xml version="1.0"?>`. I want it to include the encoding as well. Like so: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`. How do I do that with Erlang 18.2 (xmerl version 1.3.9)? I read the docs and came up with:

```
xmerl:export_simple([XmerlRecords], xmerl_xml, [{encoding, 'utf-8'}]).
```

However this produces the exact same output as before. The encoding is ignored and not included. I also tried using the `prolog` property in the third argument and it didn't change the `<?xml>` tag either.

**Edit**

While I do want the encoding attribute set in the `<?xml>` tag I also want the XML document to be encoded in that same encoding. I don't see a way of doing that with `xmerl:export/3` or `xmerl:export_simple/3`.

Answer (score 4):

I tried it out with xmerl 1.3.9 and got the `prolog` property to work, like this:

```
xmerl:export_simple([XmerlRecords], xmerl_xml,
                    [{prolog, "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"}])
```

This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, but the code in the `xmerl_xml` module is clear enough about how it uses the `prolog` attribute.

Comment: What is the `encoding` option for then? How do I set the actual encoding of the list that `export_simple/3` produces? Does it read the encoding I've set in the prolog value? The reason I want to know is because Erlang typically uses latin1, and in this application we do not support all of latin1, we only support UTF-8.